# Application Insights - Metrics

Tags: javascript, azure-application-insights

I got this error:

*"Uncaught trackPageView failed on page load calculation: [object String]"AI session renewal date is 0, session will be reset."*

I have the *instrumentationKey* right.

[**EDIT**]

This edit was made to complement the question with some comment made by [@Aaaron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780611/application-insights-metrics?noredirect=1#comment80757025_32780611).

Check out this [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/482) issue to get more information and track the resolution of it.

Comment: what version of the AI JS Sdk are you using? (at least the message implies javascript, but you have this tagged c#?)  how are you using it?  best would be to paste in your initialization code (sanitizing your iKey), and showing us how you're using it.  need more info!

Comment: Thaks you have right its javascript, i will make a edit on this post

Comment: you fixed the tag, but didn't answer anything else.  what version of the js sdk?  where did you get it?  where did you put it?  how are you using it?

Comment: @JohnGardner, I have the same problem. I'm getting this on my local dev environment in an Angular 4 app.

I'm initialising it in the constructor function of AppComponent class with the `AppInsights.downloadAndSetup({instrumentationKey: '[key here]'})` function.

Comment: ```AI (Internal): ExceptionWhileLoggingError message:"_onerror threw exception while logging error, error will not be collected: " props:"{exception:[object Object]{\messageId\:34,\message\:\AI (Internal): TrackExceptionFailed message:\\\trackException failed, exception will not be collected: \\\ props:\\\{exception:[object Object]{\\\\messageId\\\\:26,\\\\message\\\\:\\\\AI (Internal): SessionRenewalDateIsZero message:\\\\\\\\\\\\AI session renewal date is 0, session will be reset.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\}}\\\\},errorString:Error, [object ErrorEvent]}""
```

Comment: ```AI (Internal): TrackPVFailedCalc message:"trackPageView failed on page load calculation: " props:"{exception:[object Object]{\messageId\:26,\message\:\AI (Internal): SessionRenewalDateIsZero message:\\\AI session renewal date is 0, session will be reset.\\\\}}""```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/482

Comment: that's definitely a bug from something deep inside the jssdk, glad you found the issue and posted there.

Comment: @JohnGardner Sorry. I didn't answered because I didn't saw the message.

Comment: @Aaaron I will put your comments on the post

Comment: @RicardoRocha Thanks! I added comments in the GitHub issue as well. This only appears after a long delay (1-2) days after clearing cookies.